# Loading Test Data in Matrix Form into dataview in ML.Net

Tags: ml.net

I have a data with FloatLabel and FloatFeatureVector. FeatureVector size is variable. Once the model is trianed on traindata from a csv file,i want to run it on testdata that i generate on the fly.

Each `csv` file is simply the sensor data from each pump in the plant. so the featurevector is variable(since some pumps will not have all the sensors.) I can load the csv file, do feature selection and build a model on it and get the score values(regression). 
Next, I want to run it on testdata in a matrix form of `double()()` that i am generating.

The feature size in the testdata is the same as traindata. I am using the `mlcontext.data.Loadfromenumerable`.
 For the class that is required by the enumerable, i am using the one below.

```
private const int FeatureLength = 10;
public class FloatLabelFloatFeatureVectorSample
        {
            public float Label;
            [VectorType(FeatureLength)]
            public float[] Features;
        }
```

it errors if the featurelength is not a constant. 
Answers I saw elsewhere were `vague/inconsistent`
(see link: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/164)

I am using `ml.net 0.11`

Comment: Did you try using a plain 10, rather than the const variable FeatureLength?

Comment: yes. didnt work